# Pandas Comparing aggregates with original columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulty comparing a pandas dataframe with aggregate columns generated from that dataframe. Concretely if I have

```
df = Col1 Col2
     a    p
     a    q
     a    r
     b    r
     c    s
```

I'd like a boolean dataframe that is true where each entry is equal to the modal value for that column. I've tried

```
df == df.mode()
```

but that gives me `Can only compare identically labelled DataFrame objects`. I'd like something that can broadcast the second dataframe across the rows of the first dataframe to calculate the result. To be clear, in the above case I have

```
modal_df = df.mode()
modal_df = Col1 Col2
           a    r

desired_result = Col1  Col2
                 True  False
                 True  False
                 True  True
                 False True
                 False False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare `df` with `numpy array` created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (df.mode().values)
[['a' 'r']]

print (df == df.mode().values)
    Col1   Col2
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True   True
3  False   True
4  False  False
```